# Select corresponding row in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to do programming for cells in row corresponding to column A where column A has list of equipment name. Below is the vba code i come up with and the table example but still does not work. From the table, some equipment may merge with few rows. I want to select specific equipment and edit its tolerance on each row of the equipment.

| Equipment | Tolerance |
| --- | --- |
| Height Gauge |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| Caliper |  |
|  |  |

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastRow
 If Range("A" & i).MergeCells Then
  For Each cell In Range("B" & i)
   do something. . .
  Next cell
 Else
   do something. . .
 End If
Next i
```

Comment: What's the "MergeCells" about?

Comment: MergeCells will return true if the range contains merged cells. Im trying to select and edit each row individually at the next column where column A is merged.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this?:

```
For i = 1 To lastRow
    Set currentCell = Range("A" & i)
    Set firstCell = currentCell.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1)
    If currentCell.Address = firstCell.Address Then
        Range("B" & i).Value = "something"
    End If
Next i
```

What this does is, write "something" in column B only for the first row of a merged cell.

The **.MergeArea** is to get the range of the merged cells that contains the currentCell.
**Cells(1,1)** gets the first cell of that merged area.
And using below comparison to do something only if the current row is the first row of that merged area:

```
currentCell.Address = firstCell.Address
```

Comment: I have assigned values to the lastRow. Im currently trying to select and edit specific equipment tolerances on each row where the equipment may be merged.

Comment: I think I get it now, you want to edit tolerance column only for the first row of a merged row? So if "Height Gauge" is on range A2:A5, you want to put the tolerance only on cell B2?

Answer (score 0):

```
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 

    For i = 1 To lastRow
    hasFillPattern = False
    
    If Range("A" & i).MergeCells Then ' Check if the current cell is a merged cell
        Set mergedRange = Range("A" & i).MergeArea
        currentEquipment = mergedRange.Cells(1, 1).Value
        
        For Each cell In mergedRange.Rows
          If currentEquipment = "Caliper" Then
            With Range ("B" cell.Row)
              "do something"
            End With
          End If
        End For
    End If
```

Here what I ve come up with. If the equipment I specified is found, it will proceed to change corresponding cell B at each cells even if the equipment row is merged. Im using cell.Row to loop at each row.